# How do you make one AWS sagemaker pipeline trigger another one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I know you can trigger sagemaker pipelines with all kind of [events](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/new-options-trigger-amazon-sagemaker-pipeline-executions/). Can you also trigger sagemaker pipelines when another pipeline finishes it's execution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use an Amazon EventBridge event, such as

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.sagemaker"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "SageMaker Model Building Pipeline Execution Status Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "currentPipelineExecutionStatus": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then call the next pipeline as the target of the EventBridge event

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use an Amazon EventBridge event, such as

```
{
  "source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
  "detail-type": ["SageMaker Model Building Pipeline Execution Status Change"],
  "detail": {
    "currentPipelineExecutionStatus": ["Succeeded"],
    "previousPipelineExecutionStatus": ["Executing"],
    "pipelineArn": ["your-pipelineArn"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any [EventbridgeEvent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pipeline-eventbridge.html) to trigger a pipeline step. Since Eventbridge supports Sagemaker Pipeline Status Change as an event, you should be able to trigger a pipeline by another one.